# Passing values between modules in Python

Tags: python, python-module

I want to know how to pass values between modules in Python.

In generate_image.py I have:

```
def gerenate_image(fr,to,lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2):
    output_image_name = spatial_matrix.plot_spatial_data(data_array,data_array.shape[0],data_array.shape[1],float(lon1)/10000,float(lon2)/10000,float(lat1)/10000,float(lat2)/10000,fr,to)
return()
```

In overlay.py, I want to use the "output_image_name",so I tried:

```
import generate_image

def overlay():
    overlay = generate_image.output_image_name
    ....
```

but it didn't work. So how can I retrieve the value of output_image_name?Thanks.

Comment: This is one of those situations where I recommend you read the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) from cover to cover.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your function return something.

```
def generate_image(fr,to,lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2):
    return spatial_matrix.plot_spatial_data(data_array,data_array.shape[0],data_array.shape[1],float(lon1)/10000,float(lon2)/10000,float(lat1)/10000,float(lat2)/10000,fr,to)
```

Then in the other place import and call the function.

```
from yourmodule import generate_image

def overlay():
    background = generate_image(*args) # Or what ever arguments you want.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! but the problem now is that the args in generate_image involves a lots of other modules and I have to import them all..is there an easier way to pass the value of "output_image_name" in gerenate_image.py?

Answer (score 1):

In `overlay.py`:

```
def gerenate_image(fr,to,lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2):
    return spatial_matrix.plot_spatial_data(...)
```

In `generate_image.py`:

```
import generate_image

def overlay():
    overlay = generate_image.generate_image(...)
```

Comment: Yes that and on `overlay = generate_image.generate_image()` where it expects 6 arguments and you give it none.

Comment: That wouldn't be a syntax error. I've shortened the code to get the main point across.

Comment: But people that didn't know that would try to run it, get a syntax error

Comment: Calling a function with the wrong number of arguments is a `TypeError`